# how to get text value from inside text field inside table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

please have look at my code

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell()


    let textin = UITextField()
    textin.text = "value"
    cell.addSubview(textin)

    let Btin = UIButton()

    Btin.tag = indexPath.row
    Btin.addTarget(self, action:#selector(printC(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(Btin)


    return cell
}

@objc func printC(_ sender: UIButton){


}
```

i want when i click on **Btin** i can (  git text field value  ) of **textin** by func **printC**

Comment: Tell me that you click on cell? to get the value of text field?

Comment: click Btin button to get textin text

Comment: first of all try to make effective code.

Comment: what do you mean effective code sorry i am new in this field

Comment: if this is sample project then share me i will make an effective way

Comment: you can't just answer my question ?

Comment: wait am working

Comment: i also paste your code in my project. Nothing happen. Your table View show the cell and data?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a temp variable, to store the value of textfield.

```
var temp : String!
var tempLbl : UILabel!


  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


  let cell = UITableViewCell()


let textin = UITextField()
textin.text = "value"

temp = textin.text
cell.addSubview(textin)

let Btin = UIButton()

Btin.tag = indexPath.row
Btin.addTarget(self, action:#selector(printC(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
cell.addSubview(Btin)


return cell
  }

 @objc func printC(_ sender: UIButton){
   tempLbl.text = temp

  }
```

Try this one, hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Apple provides a very helpful tutorial on their website, which should answer your questions. It covers custom controls and Table Views. You can find it here: [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html)

Comment: thanks for kind replay if you have answer kindly support me